# Colossal Caves Adventure - access data source using javascript

Tags: javascript, text, adventure

I've been playing around with the idea of creating a javascript version of the original Colossal Caves Adventure, as a way to teach myself the language. The original data file for the adventure can be found here -

http://jerz.setonhill.edu/if/crowther/

I'm hoping an experienced javascripter can suggest to me the best way to store and access the text data file (which is only a few hundred lines long). At the moment I'm thinking of embedding the text in a hidden element in the html page and accessing it that way, but I know that lacks elegance. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dive in the deep end and learn AJAX while you're at it. Grabbing content *as needed* is exactly what AJAX is great at. (If you're learning JS, you *will* eventually learn AJAX)

If you really want to load all content on page land, I would recommend breaking the content into individual `<input type="hidden"`s. JavaScript grabs their contents very easily, and you can give them descriptive `id`s that will make serving the content more intuitive during programming. e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="r121" value="You come upon a fissure" />
```

Which could mean result `r` 121 is "You come upon a fissure"

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript object assigned to a variable and save this piece of code as a separate script. Keeps the data and the control code separate.

So, maybe you have a file called advdat.js that contains this:

```
advdat = {  1: "YOU ARE STANDING AT THE END OF A ROAD BEFORE A SMALL BRICK\
                BUILDING . AROUND YOU IS A FOREST. A SMALL\
                STREAM FLOWS OUT OF THE BUILDING AND DOWN A GULLY.",
            2: "YOU HAVE WALKED UP A HILL, STILL IN THE FOREST\
                THE ROAD NOW SLOPES BACK DOWN THE OTHER SIDE OF THE HILL.\
                THERE IS A BUILDING IN THE DISTANCE.",
            3: "YOU ARE INSIDE A BUILDING, A WELL HOUSE FOR A LARGE SPRING.",...
          };
```

Load this in its own script tag before loading the main program. Your data is now available in the object advdat.